# Highlight the matching characters in a string using RegExp

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to highlight the matching characters of a Regular Expression, currently I have this:

```js
var items = [
 'red',
  'green',
  'yellow',
  'blue',
  'orange',
];

var term = 're';

var regex_text = '.*';
regex_text += (term).split('').join('.*');
regex_text += '.*';
var regex = new RegExp(regex_text);

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var text = items[i];
  document.write("<br>Item: " + text);
  if (!regex.test(text)) {
     document.write(" doesn't match the term: " +  term) 
   } else {
      document.write(" matches the term in the characters: ");
      var optionText = text;
      var item = optionText.replace(regex, '<b>$1</b>');
      document.write(item);
   }
}
```

But the result is not what I'm expecting, I'm going for (without the spaces):

**r** **e** d

g **r** **e** en

yellow

blue

o **r** ang **e**

Comment: How many letters can be in `term`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your regex just to test the match. If string matches - replace letters one by one:

```js
let items = [ 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'error', 'errorer' ];

let term = 're';
let regex = new RegExp(term.split("").join(".*"));

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  let str = items[i];
  if (!regex.test(str)) {
    print("Item: " + items[i] + "; Doesn't match the term: " + term);
    continue;
  }

  let lastIndex = 0;
  for (let letter of term) {
    str = str.slice(0, lastIndex) + str.slice(lastIndex).replace(letter, fn_wrapper);
  }

  print("Item: " + items[i] + "; Matches the term in the characters: " + str);
    
  /***/
  function fn_wrapper(letter) {
    // 1-st argument of replacer-function == full match (each letter, in this case)
    let wrap = "<b>" + letter + "</b>";
    lastIndex += wrap.length;

    return wrap;
  }
}

/***/  
function print(msg) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", "<div>" + msg + "</div>");
}
```

```css
b { color: red; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is the one that I ended up using. Since it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

One way this can be achieved is by building a replacement string which matches the number of characters in the `term` variable (and those in between) so it can simultaneously replace all the characters matched by the test regex:

```js
var items = [
  'red',
  'green',
  'grey-green',
  'yellow',
  'blue',
  'orange'
];

var term = 're';
var chars = term.split('');

var regex_text = '(' + chars.join(')(.*?)(') + ')(.*)';
var regex = new RegExp(regex_text);
var replace_string = chars.map((_, i) => '<b>$'+(i*2+1)+'</b>$' + ((i+1)*2)).join('');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var text = items[i];
  document.write("<br>Item: " + text);
  if (!regex.test(text)) {
    document.write(" doesn't match the term: " + term)
  } else {
    document.write(" matches the term in the characters: ");
    var optionText = text;
    var item = optionText.replace(regex, replace_string);
    document.write(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyAce no worries. I think it's good because it does everything in a single pass, but it is definitely more complicated in the generation of the replacement string so I completely understand you going with the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve. You should use parentheses to capture a group using RegEx. The `match` function will return an array containing the captured groups.

```js
var items = [
 'red',
 'green',
 'yellow',
 'blue',
 'orange',
];

var term = 're';

var regex_text = '.*(';
regex_text += (term).split('').join('.*');
regex_text += ').*';
var regex = new RegExp(regex_text);

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 var text = items[i];
 document.write("<br>Item: " + text);
 if (!regex.test(text)) {
  document.write(" doesn't match the term: " +  term)
 } else {
  document.write(" matches the term in the characters: ");
  var optionText = text;
  let regexMatch = text.match(regex);
  var item = optionText.replace(regexMatch[1], '<b>' + regexMatch[1] +'</b>');
  document.write(item);
 }
}
```